# document list with a content type

Tags: content-type

i have a form created in microsoft word that I want to use as a document template for new list items. therefore, i've created the document template as a content type so that users see it in the droptown menu when creating a new item.

Now I want to take things a step further and display data collected in the form as "metadata" in the items record. that way when the user fills out the form, there answers will fill in columns in the item record. (just as infopath allows)

example
1. My sharepoint document list has 4 meta data fields:
First Name: 
Last Name:
Purpose:
Team:

1. User goes to the list to create a new item, opens word doc form template. the template requires the users to fill out the following information (First Name, Last Name, Purpose, Team).
2. When the user saves the word doc form, it then populates the meta data fields within the item record.

Any links a step by step on how to perform this task would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the quick parts feature in word:

http://sharepointmetadataandclassification.typepad.com/blog/2010/03/using-microsoft-word-quick-parts-to-add-metadata-to-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 0):

This should give you info on how to marry up the fields in a document info panel to columns in a sharepoint list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447589.aspx

This question on StackOverflow had something simliar too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508229/how-can-i-include-value-of-sharepoints-version-column-in-a-word-document - they were asking about the Version column but I guess you could expand it to include other columns in a list, too.